# Any way to get access.log file for analysis

Tags: joomla-2.5, google-analytics

Is there any way in Joomla 2.5 to create and get access to an access.log (visit log file) like classic UNIX and IIS servers created so I can use a web traffic analysis software like the old Hit List or WebTrends? (The online analytics tools are basically fluff and don't offer the filtering power to really see browsing patterns like nearly 20-year-old packaged software.)

Or are extension-based modules my only option?

Comment: Can you not just get it from the host? Why get it through joomla?

Comment: I would assume its a shared host or something where that is not allowed. In that case generating a log file in that way would be detrimental to speed. Writing to a file for all access with PHP instead of apache is not a great idea (in my opinion).

Comment: Even if it's a shared host, it's still worth OP asking their hosting company for access - some can provide it.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to configure access log storage location using .htaccess

Once you can control the file location - you could write a script to parse it (some exist I believe)